# Fixing TS2688: Cannot find type definition file in node_modules

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

When running tsc, I am getting many `TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'someLibrary'`
These libraries came from `node_modules`. I have tried to exclude `node_modules` and `skipLibCheck` in tsconfig, but none of them works for me. Any idea why is this happening?

Here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true,
    "emit": true,
    "compilerHost": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "es2016",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules","./node_modules/@types"],
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: if you use vscode, you can press ctrl+shift+p and select `Restart TS Server`.

Answer (score 14):

The problem was the wrong `typeRoots`. Should use the default `./node_modules/@types`

Comment: Please can you explain this answer? Your original file contains `./node_modules/@types` in the array `typeRoots`

Comment: I think he means "to add"     "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],

Comment: I had "typeRoots" in `package.json` set to different other folders (for good but unrelated reasons) and it was forgotten to mention the  otherwise“default” "node_modules/@types". adding it (as first in array) and restarting vscode fixed the warning.

Comment: So this does seem to work for me as well!  One thing to make note of is that "default" to people coming from 4.x.x is not default it seems for 5.x.x and so logic was slightly off.

Answer (score 6):

In `ts.config.json` you have put the typeRoots by default. Like this:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to the party, but I had this issue when installing non-global npm modules outside the project directory. Took me far too long to realise.

Answer (score 2):

For my NestJs Application `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]` did not solve the issue

The issue as I have a package with DevDependency "@types/x", but I did not have a dependency in package.json for that typed DevDependency.